# Android: PagerTabStrip - set colours etc. in java

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have created a PagerTabStrip for my ViewPager and it is all working fine.  Using a switch and case, I have the titles set up for each page.  However I can't find how to set the background colour or or text colour within the java.  I can change the colour in the xml, but I want the colour to change with my switch and case.

Here is my code:

EDIT: Added more code

```
public class RemViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3; 

    private ViewPager mPager; 
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_activity);


        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager); 
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter); /

          }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                   super.onBackPressed();
        } else if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        }
        else if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 2){
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter { // Sets the content of the adapter
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) { // Sets the fragment for each position

            switch (position) {

            case 0: return new Fragment1();
            case 1: return new Fragment2();
            case 2: return new Fragment3();
            }
            return null; 
        }
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { 

              switch (position) {
        case 0: return  "1"; 
        case 1: return  "2";
        case 2: return  "3";
              }
            return null;
          }

        @Override
        public int getCount() { // Sets the number of pages
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
      }
  }
```

Code of view_pager_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip 
         android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" /> 

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: there is viewpageadapter where a method pagechangelistener is there, u can implement ur code to change color

Comment: @abhishesh I havn't got a pagechangelistener - I will post the code if it is helpful

Comment: @abhishesh I added more code

Comment: post view_pager_activity.

Comment: you want to change the text color programmatically?

Comment: If you mean in the java then yes

Comment: `PagerTitleStrip titleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
titleStrip.setColor(...);`

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error on the colour - I'm using hex codes.  Also I can use this in my switch and case?

Comment: OK, I've worked out the colours, but I'm getting "unreachable code" in the switch and case"